# Error when saving files - Brackets

Tags: ide, adobe-brackets

I'm totally new to stackoverflow and programming world and I'm an undergraduate from sri lanka. These days, I'm studding html,css,javascript,bootstrap etc using Bracket editor. **But when I trying to save my works using bracket editor following error has occurred**,

```
An error occurred trying to save the file 
C:programfiles(*86)/brackets/sample/root/myProject/css/main.css. The permission do not allow you to make modification.
```

Then I have change the permission of folder to all but same error has occurred.
If anyone know how to fix this please help me.

Comment: this seems like a permissions issue on the file itself, or you still have permission issues on the folder. Either way, make sure you choose tags appropriate to your question, currently, none of the ones you picked are related to your issue at all.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice an i'm totally new to the stack overflow I understood my fault..

Comment: Now i changed the permission of  the file to write(all). Problem solved.Thank you for helping me..

Answer (score 1):

Anytime this happens.. as in "not having permissions"... always before opening the app, right click and run the app as administrator..9/10 it will allow you all the permissions you want.